# Change the data type of a column that contains text and number in Power BI Query

Tags: types, powerbi, decimal, powerquery, complex-data-types

I am struggling with a simple data type change. 
I have a column that contains both text (string) and numbers. This column is computed from a simple formula. Both the text and the numbers are important, so I need to keep them both in the same column.

What I would like to do is just to reduce the number of decimals of the numbers. Unfortunately, I cannot do that, as the data type is "Any". If I change the data type to "Decimal number", the text values show an error.

Is there a way to somehow change the data type only of the number values and to not affect the text? Or just to reduce the number of decimals of the numbers?

Attached is a picture with the current situation: the number displayed is just the result of a subtraction.

Thank you for the help!

https://ibb.co/C7yFH5F

Comment: Can you please specify from where you are getting the data? Is it possible to distinct data on the source side, before importing it in Power BI?

Comment: The data comes from a MySQL server. It comes in Date/Time format. The subtraction that I make results in a number value, but when I put this result in the graph, it is shown as a number with too many decimals. I cannot access the source and make changes there before importing to Power BI.

Comment: Ok, I get it. You can try to format column as a text with Text function, something like: Text(myField,"xxx.00")

Comment: Thank you but the format type does not work. It returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Extract function(it's located in the UI under Transform>Extract), and provide a range of characters. This will work if none of the text cells have more characters than the range provided.
It generates this code:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step", {{#"Your Column", each Text.Middle(_, 0, 12), type text}})
```

In this case I inserted from 0 to 12.
It is not elegant but it might work for your specific case.

Comment: thank you but still no working. the problem is now that it cannot distinguish between days and hours. Shortly said, I just want to have a column that shows the number of days left. This column is in Duration format, but when I convert it to number, the numbers in Power Query are right. When I add them to the graph, they show something else.

Comment: Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I managed in the end to do it. I just made other columns with the result as a text and then created another one using LEFT(Text;"X"). It displays the number in reasonable way and it is also correct. Many thanks for the help! It certainly pushed me towards the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new column with a formula that converts your number. To avoid errors on lines with text, you must use the error tracking function.

```
try otherwise
```

After the word "try" the function of converting the number from the column. After "otherwise" the column without conversion

Comment: Thanks for the suggesiton! I have already found another way to change it.